# How to prevent html injection in Ionic application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I develop a demo app where user can create a post by providing following inputs(ion-input type=“text”).

While testing some user will type some HTML scripting and the result you can see on attached image.

So my question is how can we prevent this type of inputs in ionic ?[image]

Comment: Is your "output component" using [innerHtml] ?

Comment: Do you mean this, <p [innerHTML]="userPost.longDescription"></p> ?  Yes I am using this for displaying text

Answer (score 0):

What if you displayed the input in the "p" tag like this

```
<p>{{userPost.longDescription}}</p>
```

Comment: No some time I get 'some statements line </br> tag' so I need to use innerHTML for that, So I want to check in ion-input and replace some scripting corrector with white space  so that will change HTML injection to simple text ?

Comment: What about using \n tags instead of html linebreaks?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found out work around solution by simply changing the message(Input value).

It's not a proper solution but in my case it is cool alternative.

Solution for disable HTML or any kind of scripting.

-- Simply replace some basic special symbol to white space which is used while writing a script.

```
 Example: < > ( ) ' " / \ *; = { } ` (back tick) % + ^! -
 const str = `Click <a href='www.google.com'> here</a> to reset your password`;
console.log(str.replace(/[\\#+$~`":;!=*<>{}]/g, ""));
```

In my case user not using some symbols for describing problem(Message).